# automake: How do I copy files to the build directory?

Tags: automake

I am autotoolizing a library project, and this project has some example programs.  I want the example programs to be distributed in the dist, but *not* installed.

Currently the demo programs are organized like thus:

```
src/*.cpp (library source)
include/*.h (library headers)
demos/demo.cpp (example program)
demos/RunDemo (script to run demo)
```

It is important that RunDemo be runnable after building the software, without requiring the "install" step.

So far I have been able to build the "demo" exectuable using a `noinst_PROGRAMS` target.  However, after `make` in a VPATH build, the following is available:

```
build/src/.libs/libxxx.so  (etc..)
build/demos/demo
```

As you can see, the RunDemo script needed to execute "demo" is not copied to the $(builddir).  I have tried a few things, e.g., adding `RunDemo` to `dist_noinst_SCRIPTS`, as well as adding my own copy targets and trying to hook `all`..  no matter what I try, I always get the output,

```
$ make RunDemo
make: Nothing to be done for `../../../projects/demo/RunDemo'.
```

I seem to be unable to create a target in the builddir that says "if this file is not in the builddir, copy it from the srcdir."

Is this possible with automake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make files accessible in the build tree after the  `./configure` step using the `AC_CONFIG_LINKS` macro (provided with `autoconf`) in your configure.ac script. It will create a symbolic link if possible, otherwise it will copy the file.

In your case it would look like

```
AC_CONFIG_LINKS([demos/RunDemo:demos/RunDemo])
```

From the [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Links.html#Configuration-Links):

> Macro: AC_CONFIG_LINKS (dest:source..., [cmds], [init-cmds])
>
> Make AC_OUTPUT link each of the existing files *source* to the
>   corresponding link name *dest*. Makes a symbolic link if possible,
>   otherwise a hard link if possible, otherwise a copy. The *dest* and
>   *source* names should be relative to the top level source or build
>   directory

Using `dist_noinst_SCRIPTS` is still necessary for the file to be distributed.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with directories rather than just files?

Comment: I assume that `AC_CONFIG_LINKS([directory:directory])` doesn't work? I'm not sure why that would be, but you could try writing a command to copy it with `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS` using the `srcdir` and `builddir` variables.

Comment: AC_CONFIG_LINKS really wants to work on filies, but you can do directories if you are careful about how you test for $srcdir -- you have to configure it so you never run AC_CONFIG_LINKS unless you are in a build directory.